# How to install all packages from a scope

Tags: npm, npm-install

Is it possible to install all packages from a given scope for example:

```
npm install @myscope/* --save
```

Comment: Hi there gevik. Pased on your parameter `--save` I'm assuming you're using an outdated version of npm? Starting with v5 `--save` is default.

Comment: Since your question is some months old: did you succeed?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think it's possible with npm itself, but by combining your swiss army knife of unix tools – or windows tools.

I'm on Windows and using cmder to get some level of Unix tools available:

1. Obtain a table with all packages in the scope, columns will be separated by tabs.
2. Use `awk` to only output the first column of that table, it’s the actual package name, including the scope, like `@org/package`
3. Use that output with `npm install`, to actually install these packages

```
npm install $(npm search @org --parseable | awk '{print $1}')
```

Comment: I'm sure you can achieve the same with some windows bash commands.

Comment: You can merge the 2 commands to 1 and use a single command without temporary file:

`npm install $(npm search @org --parseable | awk '{print $1}')`

Comment: Thanks again, I updated the answer. Hope this works across different windows tools as well.